# how to use onActivityResult(..) if the activity is called from a menu

Tags: android, android-activity, menu, android-intent, barcode

This is my problem:

```
class main extends menuActivity{
  //
  ..
  //
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (resultCode == 0) 
        camera_barcode = INTENT.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
     }
  }
}
```

the INTENT is created in the menuActivity class:

```
public class menuActivity extends Activity {

    public INTENT;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

       //
       INTENT = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
       INTENT.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
       startActivityForResult(INTENT, 0);
       //
    }
}
```

The problem is that the String camera_barcode is null, can't understand why.

Q: if instead of QR_CODE_MODE I want to scan 1d barcodes?
R: cameraScan.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");

Thank you!!

Comment: This link will fit for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114485/use-onactivityresult-android/39987477#39987477

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finish the activity you are starting for result like this

```
  Bundle b = new Bundle();
  b.putString(key, value);
  Intent i = getIntent(); //gets the intent that called this intent
  i.putExtras(b);
  setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
  finish();
```

Comment: I usually use the constant Activity.RESULT_OK instead of random 222.

Comment: Activity.RESULT_OK = -1 :D Recall, i said that oAR() will be called for every positive integer :D

Comment: @Nikola Despotoski, You understood the documentation in a wrong way. It said about request code to be non-negative, not about result code. So it's perfectly fine to use `Activity.RESULT_OK` for `setResult()`. But if you call `startActivityForResult(intent, -1)`, then `onActivityResult()` will not be called.

Comment: Indeed, my bad, I've mixed result and request, I was distracted for a moment. :D

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where you create the intent. If you've used Activity's `startActivityForResult()` method, then you'll receive results in `onActivityResult()` function.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for the answer!
I defined a public Intent in the MenuActivity class, and now things seem to work. The only problem is that the ZXing return intent is null :/ 

This is my code:
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == 0) {
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String camera_barcode = cameraScan.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
....
}

And the string camera_barcode is always null

Comment: I can see your code in the question. So you basically receive result, but intent is null? You should update your question with this information.