# How to make a click on an item in the global search provider (Quick Search Box) go to the correct Activity

Tags: android

I have an application that has the structure:

- Activity A

  - Activity B

    - Activity C

In activity B I call startActivityForResult on Activity C.

In Activity C I have a search provider where the user can search addresses and then return them to activity B.

This works great, but when I introduce the search results in the Quick Search Box ([Reference Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html)) then a click on the suggestion will go straight to Activity C. Calling finish on that activity will then not do what I want (returning to B with the result).

So any suggestions on how to rewrite this to work in both scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the result between activities

Activity C --> send the result to ---> Activity B.

[how to use onActivityResult(..) if the activity is called from a menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780325/how-to-use-onactivityresult-if-the-activity-is-called-from-a-menu/6780560)

See my answer here. Its the same, mind the comments below.

Comment: Hmm, I had hoped I didn't have to do that but as I cannot specify a separate intent for the quick search box to trigger, then I guess I have to rewrite this :-(

Comment: No no no. You are still in ActivityC, you are finishing it, when finishing you just use INTENT just to send the data. Not intent for another activity.

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:launchMode="singleTop"` for Activity C in manifest.