# How to go in previous activity with setResult?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have to go to parent activity when any list item is clicked, with setResult.

```
list.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("gaurav", "list is clicked");

                    moveToEvent();
                }
            });
```

My moveToEvent method is :

```
public void moveToEvent() {
    Log.d("gaurav", "Move to evnet");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    this.setResult(5, intent);
    // this.startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();

}
```

Using this code I am able to come back to parent activity two or three times, After that its not coming back to parent activity and refresh its own activity. I am not able to find its solution. Kindly help me in this issue

I also tried onBackPressed method but same result.

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method
   Intent intent = new Intent(); 
   setResult(5, intent); 
   finish();

  super.onBackPressed();
  }
```

Kindly suggest me where i am doing mistake.

Comment: what does it mean as it is going some time and then after it is not going - means activity is not finishing ?? You debugged ?? finish() is getting called all the time ??

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780325/how-to-use-onactivityresult-if-the-activity-is-called-from-a-menu)                                                                                                                                 Try this [tutorial](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html) for deep explaination                                                                             
Hope it helps 

nJoy!!

Comment: In my code finish is mentioned, this block of code is running every time. what can be issue in this. should i post onActivityForResult method of parent activity.

Comment: @MiteshAgrawal its not working.its working for two or three times , after that its refrshing its own activity

Comment: It means after some time your activity is not getting finished ? right ??

Comment: ys, its strange. When i click on list 10 times 5 times its going to parent activity and 5 times its refreshes current activity.

Comment: clear your stack activity using addflag on Intent, might help. Like this      mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: Wow , thax Mitesh Agarwal , its works for me. Thanx for saving my day. :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to start your ParentActivity with

```
Intent i = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, UploadImage.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

And then write this in your ParentActivity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
       //your code
    } else {        
    }       
}
```

And then in your 2nd Activity write this

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: gaurav is saying activity itself is not getting finished, is your cade is helpful for the same ??

Answer (score 0):

I used this to solve my problem . This code will be in parent activity.

`Intent intent = new Intent(AddEvent.this, AddVenue.class);
        intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 222);
        ((Activity) AddEvent.this).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);`

This is the key line to solve this problem.

```
intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```