# Use onactivityresult android

Tags: android

I want to call a method from `mainactivity` in other activities. For that, I've researched a lot and found that using `OnActivityResult` is the best option. Can anyone please explain how to use this method with the help of an example? I've gone through similar questions but found them confusing.
Thanks!

EDIT:I have a custom dialog activity in my app. It asks the users whether they want to start a new game or not and it has two buttons yes and no. I want to implement the above method only to get the pressed button.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Define constant

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

Call your custom dialog activity using intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,
                    CustomDialogActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent , REQUEST_CODE);
```

Now use onActivityResult to retrieve the result

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE  && resultCode  == RESULT_OK) {

                String requiredValue = data.getStringExtra("key");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, ex.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

In custom dialog activity use this code to set result

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("key", value);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Comment: What should I use in my Custom Dialog?

Comment: we have set requestCode to 1 if everything goes well then RESULT_OK will be 1 so in on activityResult we can check if(requestCode == RESULT_OK).

For setting result we have used setResult in custom dialog activity. we can put some data with key-value pair as mentioned above.

For getting that data in onActivityResult use that key name to retrieve its value.

Comment: it shows 'cannot find symbole' error on super.onActivityResult. I am trying to use it with Reac Native Module. which extends ReactApplicationContext.  What is required here?

Comment: Warning! This answer has mistake (but it works on some devices). Use for set result Intent intent = new Intent();

Answer (score 7):

### **Start the Activity:**

you do need to pass an additional integer argument to the `startActivityForResult()` method.You may do it by defining a constant or simply put an integer.The integer argument is a "request code" that identifies your request. When you receive the result Intent, the callback provides the same request code so that your app can properly identify the result and determine how to handle it.

```
static final int ASK_QUESTION_REQUEST = 1;
// Create an Intent to start SecondActivity
Intent askIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

// Start SecondActivity with the request code
startActivityForResult(askIntent, ASK_QUESTION_REQUEST);
```

### **Return The Result:**

After completing your work in second activity class simply set the result and call that activity where it comes from and lastly don't forget to write `finish()` statement.

```
// Add the required data to be returned to the FirstActivity
            sendIntent.putExtra(Result_DATA, "Your Data");

            // Set the resultCode to Activity.RESULT_OK to
            // indicate a success and attach the Intent
            // which contains our result data
            setResult(RESULT_OK, sendIntent);

            // With finish() we close the SecondActivity to
            // return to FirstActivity
            finish();
```

### **Receive The Result:**

When you done with the subsequent activity and returns, the system calls your activity's `onActivityResult()` method. This method includes three arguments:

@The request code you passed to `startActivityForResult()`.
 @A result code specified by the second activity. This is either `RESULT_OK` if the operation was successful or `RESULT_CANCELED` if the operation failed
@An Intent that carries the result data.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 1
    if (requestCode == ASK_QUESTION_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            final String result = data.getStringExtra(SecondActivity.Result_DATA);

            // Use the data - in this case display it in a Toast.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Result: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my example.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == Image_Request_Code && resultCode ==RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            FilePathUri = data.getData();

            try {

                // Getting selected image into Bitmap.
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), FilePathUri);

                // Setting up bitmap selected image into ImageView.
                SelectImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                // After selecting image change choose button above text.
                ChooseButton.setText("Image Selected");

            }
            catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }*strong text*
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (requestCode == 2000)
    {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            try {

                Uri selectedImages = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImages,
                        filePathColumn,null,null,null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                receivedImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(receivedImageBitmap);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```