# How to call previous activity from new activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In my project, I have 3 activities, A-> B -> C. In C activity it has order button, after clicked order button I also have to pass a bundle by intent to A activity and I would like A activity to be showed again. How could I just show A activity again?

Thanks,

Comment: You can close your Front Activities else use Fragments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use onactivityresult android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114485/use-onactivityresult-android)

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android

Comment: in bundle  what do you want to pass to A activity?

Answer (score 0):

> Depend on your requirement , if you wants to finish activty B and c
>   on Button Click then use Flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP with intent
>   flag. in this case on newIntent will be called, you can get bundle
>   from it.

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    } 

if you do not wants to close activity B and C then use 

Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
intent.putextras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

> if any issue then let me know.

Comment: Intent i=new Intent(mContext,MainActivity.class);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(i);     I used this lines of code before to call MainActivity.java, it is ok, the problem the fragment in MainActivity.java doesn't show form stat data such as user selected item of spinner and user entered data of edittext.