# How do I throw data in two activities and make that data in one activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-button

I have a scenario when user input in an activity and when the user clicks the button will display the data input in other activities and when the user clicks the button will appear all inputted data

In one activity

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnMoveToKereta2) {
        goToForm(TransferKereta2.class);
    }
}

private void goToForm(Class<TransferKereta2> transferKereta2Class) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TransferKereta2.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.FullName, inpFullName.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra(Constants.NickName, inpNickName.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra(Constants.Age, inpAge.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And if user click `goToForm` will go to `TransferKereta2.class`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnMove) {
        goToTransfer(DetailKereta.class);
    }
}

private void goToTransfer(Class<DetailKereta> DetailKeretaClass) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DetailKereta.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.Jumlah, inpJumlah.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra(Constants.Dari, inpAsal.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra(Constants.Ke, inpTujuan.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

If user click `goToTransfer` the all data will display in `DetailKereta.class`

DetailKereta.class

```
        TextView tv_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_fullName);
    TextView tv_nname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_nickName);
    TextView tv_umur = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_umur);
    TextView tv_jumlah = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_jumlah);
    TextView tv_asal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_asal);
    TextView tv_tujuan = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_tujuan);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    tv_name.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Constants.FullName));
    tv_nname.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Constants.NickName));
    tv_umur.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Constants.Age));
    tv_jumlah.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Constants.Jumlah));
    tv_asal.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Constants.Dari));
    tv_tujuan.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Constants.Ke));
```

I use constant to save the data from 2 input activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to propagate the extras from activity to activity.

add

```
intent.putExtras(this.getIntent());
```

to each of the methods that start a new intent, so that you can also send the intents the current activity was created with.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`
which throwback the data from second activity to calling activity.
See in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114485/use-onactivityresult-android)