# How to set results from next activity to previous activity in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, resultset

I have 2 activities one main and other contacts
from main i am going to contact activity to select contact but when i set main activity after selecting contacts it recreates the main activity like new

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String clicktemplate = arrayListplayer.get(i).getTitle1();
    Toast.makeText(ContactsSelect.this ,arrayListplayer.get(i).getTitle1(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsSelect.this, PlanSMS.class);
    intent.putExtra("key_clicktemplate1", clicktemplate);
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

Here is my code 
I am starting new activity here using intent and pass clicktemplate variable
but when i select another contact second time the first one disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use startActivityForResult

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String clicktemplate = arrayListplayer.get(i).getTitle1();

    Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsSelect.this, PlanSMS.class);
    intent.putExtra("key_clicktemplate1", clicktemplate);
    startActivityForResult(intent,1933);
}
```

example : [Use onactivityresult android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114485/use-onactivityresult-android)

Comment: Thanks i tried this and it actually works and i understand the code as well

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
startActivityForResult()
```

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result