# How to access TextView and progress bar presented in fragment class from another class

Tags: java, android

I am calling a method in fragment from another class. After that method call, I want to change some textviews and progress bar visibility. But I cant able to achieve this. And I dont know how to access a fragment class from another class. Because I am calling a method in fragment class from another class so oncreateview is not called. Please anybody help me out to solve this.

This is my fragment class

```
public class MyClass extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment implements MoneyListener{
  private TextView moneyTv;
private ProgressBar pBar;
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_call_packages, container, false);
       pBar=view.findViewById(R.id.pBar);
        moneyTv=view.findViewById(R.id.money);
getMoneyFromRtrofit(getContext);
       pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
/* this method is for getting response from retrofit and setting in money text view
I want to pass only context here, from any class and send request to retrofit and again want to update the value in money Textview.
While calling this method from another class getting -->Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference*/
public void getMoneyFromRtrofit(Context context)
{
RetrofitRequest retrofitReq=new RetrofitRequest(context,this/*passing money listener here*/);
retrofitReq.getMoney();
}
@Override
    public void onSuccesfulResponse(MoneyObject money) {
         pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     moneyTv.setText(money.getBalance);

    }
}
```

This is my another class,

```
public class Updated extends Activity implements RechargeListener{
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);
        }
  @Override
    public void getSuccessResponse(String message) {
    MyClass myClass=new MyClass();
/* passing context to MyClass*/
    myClass.getMoneyFromRtrofit(getApplicationContext);
}
}
```

Comment: Post some code to for understanding the question.

Comment: I have added the codes.Kindly look into that@Zahra

Comment: You should move the Retrofit code to a separate class that isn't an instance of a Fragment

Answer (score 2):

If some work in being done in Updated Activity and result should be represented in your `MyClass` fragment , you should override `startActivityForResult` in `MyClass` fragment.
Then you can get your expected data from `onActivityResult`'s intent and update the mentioned TextView.
So there is no need to call `MyClass` fragment's getMoneyFromRtrofit method.In this case the `Updated Activity` will call it's own retrofit call and it's not excpecting a fragment to have that method .and activity would be reusable .

```
 mybtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity,Updated.class);  
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with requestCode 2  
            }  
        });  
    }  
 // Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity  
    @Override  
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
       {  
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
                  // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
                   if(requestCode==2)  
                         {  
                            String balance=data.getStringExtra("BALACE");   
                            moneyTv.setText(balance);  
                         }  
     }
```

And in second Activity which name is Updated (it isn't not good naming) set data:

```
public String getMoneyFromRtrofit(Context context)
{
  String balance;
  RetrofitRequest retrofitReq=new RetrofitRequest(context,this/*passing money listener here*/);
   retrofitReq.getMoney();
}
@Override
    public void onSuccesfulResponse(MoneyObject money) {

     balance=money.getBalance;

    }

 return balance;
}
```

Then send result :

```
somebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
                @Override  
                public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                    String balance=getMoneyFromRtrofit;  
                    Intent intent=new Intent();  
                    intent.putExtra("BALANCE",balance);  
                    setResult(2,intent);  
                    finish();//finishing activity  
                }  
            });
```

Comment: check this link about onActivityResult :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114485/use-onactivityresult-android

Comment: thankyou I found a solution..when overriding on start() in fragment,I am call retrofit request. So my cost is updated.