# Right Way to update one Item of Recyclerview onResume via Backbutton from other activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

1. MainActivity has a `Recyclerview` with a list of items.
2. OnClick on one of the items `UpdateActivity` is started where the item can be changed
3. When navigating via clicking BackButton I would like to only update this particular single `RecyclerViewItem`

What is the **cleanest** way to achieve this? Where should I update the item? 
If I use intents in the overridden BackButton action and start the `MainActivity` from there, the `RecyclerView` is empty and I would need to load all items again.

I could pass all the loaded items to the `UpdateActivity` with the position information and update the item in the UpdateActivity but I would like to avoid passing all the data to this activity if there is a cleaner way to solve this in `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then Start the update activity by expecting a result using **startActivityForResult**() and while pressing the backbutton finish the **UpdateActivity** and send a intent. Then onreceiving the intent in the MainActivity try to use adapter.notifyItemInserted() method of RecyclerView adapter and update it.

Try using this method

```
adapter.notifyItemInserted(); //in case of addition
adapter.notifyItemChanged(position); // in case of any updation
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I load a lot of data into the list and before the user switiches to the UpdateActivity, he sees a full list. When resuming he would suddendly see an empty list that gradually fills up again.

My vision is to have the single item updated before the user sees the MainActivity again.

Comment: See the above explanation in the Answer.

Comment: Thanks will try that out, sounds straightforward

Answer (score 0):

**As per my point of views**

**#** You can hold the clicked item position once it is clicked in Mainactivity(list activity), and in onStart/onRestart if that position variable is not null/0 just reload that particular item.

**OR**

**#** you can pass back the position or item unique id with onActivityResult method from update activity.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would be passing your current clicked item's data to `UpdateActivity`, so after update is done, you can send that updated data back to `MainActivity`.

And then you can just replace that data in your list and call `notifyItemChanged` for your adapter.

[More info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int))

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this without passing all data.

- if you are using DataBinding you can just send this particular item and make you UiModel extends BaseObservable and change any attribute the changes the item like this, this will reflect your UI without extra code

  ```
  class ItemViewModel(): BaseObservable() {
  @get:Bindable
  var changableItem: DataType by Delegates.observable(changableItem) { _, _, _ ->
      notifyPropertyChanged(BR.changableItem)
  }
  ```
- You can use on Activity result and change the recycler view item accordingly

You can find an example here: [Use onactivityresult android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114485/use-onactivityresult-android)

- You can use EventBus using RXJava or any other library and use RecyclerView `notifyItemChanged`

Personally I prefer the first option.
feel free to ask for any clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to store your datalist and clicked position somewhere.After you return to the activity, update your recyclerview with the changed data using `notifyItemChange(pos,payload)`