# Passing values between activity

Tags: java, android

I should show 2 `TextView` in `MainActivity` "stringadaA" and "numerodaB" , namely the string and the number put in the 2 activities A and B.These values must not be lost in the transition between the activities but must change only when they are changed by the user. I managed to do it but when I press the "Ritorna" button to go back to the `MainActivity` it does not  maintain both the results as I would expect, why are not both saved if I insert  values in `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`?

Thanks in advance

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView stringaA;
    TextView numeroB;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        stringaA = findViewById(R.id.stringadaA);
         numeroB= findViewById(R.id.numerodaB);
        Button btnA = findViewById(R.id.btnactivitya);
        Button btnB= findViewById(R.id.btnactivityb);
        final EditText editText= findViewById(R.id.editactivitya);
        btnA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        Bundle extras= getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras!=null){
            String value = extras.getString("stringaA");
            String number =extras.getString("numero");
            stringaA.setText(value);
            numeroB.setText(number);
        }

        btnB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        String stringa= stringaA.getText().toString();
        outState.putString("STRINGA", stringa);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        String stringa= savedInstanceState.getString("STRINGA");

    }
}
```

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);

        final EditText edtA= findViewById(R.id.editactivitya);
        Button returnbtnA= findViewById(R.id.ritornaallaprincipaleA);
        returnbtnA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
               i.putExtra("stringaA", edtA.getText().toString());
               startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

        final EditText edtb= findViewById(R.id.editactivityb);
        Button returnbtnb= findViewById(R.id.ritornaallaprincipaleB);
        returnbtnb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("numero", edtb.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

XML CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/testo1"
     android:textSize="30dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Main Activity"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 <Button
         android:id="@+id/btnactivitya"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
         android:textSize="20dp"
         android:text="Activity A"
         android:layout_below="@+id/testo1"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     />
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnactivityb"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
     android:textSize="20dp"
     android:text="Activity B"
     android:layout_below="@+id/btnactivitya"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/stringaA"
     android:layout_below="@id/btnactivityb"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Stringa da Activity A:"/>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/stringadaA"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/stringaA"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:textSize="20dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/stringaB"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Numero da Activity B"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:layout_below="@+id/stringadaA"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/numerodaB"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/stringaB"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:textSize="20dp"
 />
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ActivityA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Activity A"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/InserisciA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ActivityA"
        android:text="Inserisci stringa"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editactivitya"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/InserisciA"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ritornaallaprincipaleA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editactivitya"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/InserisciA"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Ritorna"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ActivityB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Activity B"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/InserisciB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ActivityA"
        android:text="Inserisci numero"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editactivityb"
        android:layout_below="@+id/InserisciB"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ritornaallaprincipaleB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ritorna"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editactivityb"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: vincent what do you want to obtain, please read better the post, or chat with me in Italian

Comment: The main activity must display the values entered via TextView. These values must not be lost in the transition between the activities but must change only when they are changed by the user.The values must not be lost when the app is closed and reopened. @trocchietto

Comment: Please see my edit, you should focus to one question per time.1) Values that are not lost in the transaction between activities or 2) vallues not be lost when app is closed and reopened. 3)Validate text as number of string. In stackoverflow usually we ask one question per post

Comment: Point 1 is the main one I have to do then the others are secondary

Comment: So please edit better your question (RIvedi per piacere la domanda, cosi ti aiuto io o qualcun altro)

Comment: Please post also layout of `activity_a` and `activity_b` (Aggiungi gli altri due xml per piacere)

Comment: I edited, okay now?

Comment: No, still you should do two things: 1) insert the two other files under res layout in your project on the right of Android studio 2) explain this"when I press the "Ritorna" button to go back to the MainActivity it does not, what insert is not saved why?"  You mean that when you go back to MainActivity you do not see the change right(Il risultato non e' passato da `activity_a` o b al `MainActivity` giusto)?

Comment: now I see the two layouts thanks, let me see..

Comment: it works as expected if you go from ActivityB or Activity A back you get the result you need, of course only one per time, is the problem that you want to see in `MainActivity` both of them?

Comment: Yes yes exactly

Comment: eh eh, ok I am gonna reply you, there are several ways to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use startActivityForResult method to invoke ActivityA and ActivityB. And override onActivityResult method in your MainActivity.

1. Here, 100 is a int value request code for ActivityA :

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityA.class);    
startActivityForResult(i,100);
```

2. Here : Here, 101 is a int value request code for ActivityB :

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(i,101);
```

3. In ActivityA, here, result code is `RESULT_OK`

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("stringaA", edtA.getText().toString());
setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
finish();
```

4. In ActivityB, here, result code is `RESULT_OK`

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("numero", edtb.getText().toString());
setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
finish();
```

5. Override onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data) method in your MainActity class

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent 
        data {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
    switch(requestCode){  
        case 100:  
            stringaA.setText(data.getStringExtra("stringaA"));  
            break;  
        case 101:  
            numeroB.setText(data.getStringExtra("numero"));  
            break;  
    }
}
```

Comment: well Dimpy has  directly replied with some code !  Vincent now from both the replies you should have now clearer how it works, please  see how Dimpy does not recreate `MainActivity` but directly set the result finishing the activity. Creating back MainActivity as you do vincent this is not how developers do, you want to avoid in future. my upvote Dimpy thanks

Comment: Work, thanks!, How can I make the EditText for the string accept only letters and that the EditText for the number accept only digits?

Comment: @Dimpy : Nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Is working as expected you go from one of the two created `Activity` via Intent, then you go back to the `MainActivity` and you have *only  one* result. Not both of them, this is because it does not remain in memory since you RECREATE from `Activity A` and `Activity B` the `MainActivity`
, this is not the way to do it, even if could work.

What you want to do do is to learn how the backstack of the activities in Android work, and give a `finish()` command when "Ritorna" is clicked in this way the activity  will terminate and use onActivityResult() as explained in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114485/use-onactivityresult-android)
you will get the result back (Instead to launch an explicit Intent to MainActivity again you will terminate the fragment and give back the result to MainActivity, in this way will be available in Main Activity because you will have MainActivity Below and on top one of the activities)
Once you have your result back assign it to the TextView and will remain in memory!

The second thing you asked me regarding maintaining the data if you close and open the app can be obtained on several ways. One is via `SharedPreferences` another one via a database, for instance `Room` or `MySQL`

EDIT:
in reply to your comment, you can add the attribute

> android:inputType="number"
>   to accept only numbers

if you want only strings, alphabet letters for instance you can use this attribute

> android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" >

Comment: Could you check out my other post? maybe you could help me.

Comment: I did it @vincent , please see the edit, and please accept one of the two replies marking it as accepted