# onActivityResult not called in Android

Tags: android, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I have the following code

```
public void changeContentOnClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChangeNodeContentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("SELECTED_NODE_ID", selectedNode.getNodeId());
    intent.putExtra("SELECTED_NODE_CONTENT", selectedNode.getNodeContent());
    startActivityForResult(intent,RESULT_OK);
    Log.d(TAG, "Can I get here?");
    onActivityResult(RESULT_OK, RESULT_OK, intent);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String editedNodeId = data.getStringExtra("EDITED_NODE_ID");
            String editedNodeContent = data.getStringExtra("EDITED_NODE_CONTENT");
            Node nodeChecker = new Node(editedNodeId);
            Node editedNode = new Node(editedNodeId, editedNodeContent);
            Log.d(TAG, editedNode.toString());
            nodes.set(nodes.indexOf(nodeChecker), editedNode);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Somehow, after startActivityForResult method is called, everything stops. The log with message "Can I get here?" is never printed and I don't understand why not. I have followed the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114485/use-onactivityresult-android) topic, but somehow couldn't make it work. Do I call the onActivityResult in the wrong way or place? Please help me out!

The that should send back some info from the ChangeNodeContentActivity and the one that handles the result code is the following on click listener:

```
public void changeContentOnClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    selectedNode.setNodeContent(nodeContentDisplay.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("EDITED_NODE_ID", selectedNode.getNodeId());
    intent.putExtra("EDITED_NODE_CONTENT", selectedNode.getNodeContent());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    Log.d(TAG, selectedNode.toString());
    finish();
}
```

Comment: `startActivityForResult(intent,RESULT_OK);` That should be `startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);`.

Comment: You are calling onActivityResult() yourself. Dont do that. Remove that line. You should wait till it gets called automatically when the new activity is closed/finished.

Comment: Yes, figured out that I should not be calling it myself haha. But your first comment did the trick. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`startActivityForResult()` method receives an `intent` and `requestCode`, so you should change it to:

```
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
```

And `onActivityResult()` method is automatically called when returning from the activity, so you should remove the direct call you made to the method, i.e. `onActivityResult(RESULT_OK, RESULT_OK, intent)`