# How to make rest of methods start after new intent activity is finished

Tags: android, function, android-intent, stack-trace

I call new activity from one function like below.

I want to make loadRoundFromExercise() ~ updateRound() methods starts after new activity called from openRegisterPopupActivity() is finished

I thought to put sleep method. but I can't estimate how long user are going to put text.

So.. how can I fix this? plz help me.

Thank you.

```
adapter.setRoutineListener(new HealthRoutineViewHolder.Listener() {
@Override
public void onAddItem(ExerciseLog exerciseLog) {
    setupLogReference(exerciseLog);

    openRegisterPopupActivity(); // I call new activity here by intent.

    loadRoundFromExercise();

    convertToRoundLog();

    updateRound();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `startActivityForResult()` and the `onActivityResult()` callback.  These basically let Activity A start Activity B and then return a result back to Activity A.

[Use onactivityresult android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114485/use-onactivityresult-android)

Comment: it has a same result. onActivityResult starts after the functions are finished

Comment: The other functions get called from inside `onActivityResult()`.